# How to create dynamically in HTNL ng-template? (Angular)

Tags: html, angular, firebase

I want to build a slideshow component.I used ng-bootstrap:Carousel
 (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples).

But the situation now is that the number of images I create is predetermined (by the number of: `<ng-template ngbSlide> </ng-template ngbSlide>` that are in the HTML file).

But I would like to build it dynamically.

I tried to use `<div * ngFor = "let dataImage of images">`, but it didn't work for me.

I would be very happy if you could share your solution ideas with me.

I attach the non-dynamic code. Thanks!!!

`slideshow.comonent.html`:

```
<ngb-carousel *ngIf="images">
    <ng-template ngbSlide>
      <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
        <img [src]="images[0]" alt="Random first slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>"{{titles[0]}}"</h3>
        <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbSlide>
      <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
        <img [src]="images[1]" alt="Random second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>"{{titles[1]}}"</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbSlide>
      <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
        <img [src]="images[2]" alt="Random third slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>"{{titles[2]}}"</h3>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-carousel>
```

`slideshow.comonent.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

export interface Pic {
  image: string;
  title: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slideshow',
  templateUrl: './slideshow.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slideshow.component.css']
})

export class SlideshowComponent {
  private dbData;//will hold object from firebase
  @Input() dbPath: string;
  public images: Array<Pic> = [];
  public titles: Array<Pic> = [];

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private db: AngularFireDatabase, private router: Router) {}

 ngOnInit():void{
  this.dbData=this.db.list(this.dbPath).valueChanges()
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      this.images.push(data[i]["image"]);
      this.titles.push(data[i]["title"]);
    }
  })
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's only use a *ngFor in the ng-template and give differents "id"

```
<ngb-carousel #myCarousel="ngbCarousel" >
  <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let image of images;let i = index" id="{{i}}">
    <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
       <img [src]="image" alt="Random first slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-caption">
       <h3>titles[i]</h3>
       <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
    </div>
  <ng-template/>
</ngb-carousel>
```

NOTE: You has two separates arrays, so, the ngFor has a `let i=index` and use titles[i] for the title, if you create an array of objects instead of two arrays use the properties of the object